# Concatenate files from different folders in bash

Tags: bash, unix, concatenation

I have a directory containing 227 subdirectories, each of which contains a file with the same name (in.BV) that I would like to concatenate.

i.e.

```
Directory
---------Subdirectory1
---------------in.BV various other files
---------Subdirectory2
---------------in.BV various other files
```

etc

These files called in.BV contain only text, and I would like to simply concatenate them into a single long text file.

I'm a novice, and this is what I have tried so far:

```
for d in */
do
        (cd $d cat *in.BV >> Newin.txt)
done
```

This gave me a blank `Newin.txt`. This exceeds my current understanding of bash scripting.

Thanks in advance!

Richie

Comment: The first comment is wrong. That will only go one layer deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are in the `Directory` directory:

```
cat */in.BV >Newin.txt
```

Assuming you are somewhere above `Directory`:

```
shopt -s globstar
cat **/in.BV >Newin.txt
shopt -u globstar
```

This sets the `globstar` shell option in `bash`.  With the option set, you may use `**` to match any pathname (`*` only matches up to the next `/` in a pathname, but `**` matches across `/`).

After the `cat`, which creates `Newin.txt` in the current directory, I unset the `globstar` option.

If you have *a lot of* files and if the shell has issues executing `cat` because the command line becomes too long, then see [varlogtim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50327720/931027).

---

With new information given in comments below (files are to be concatenated in order depending on the subdirectory name):

Assuming you are in `Directory`:

```
cat Subdirectory{1..227}/in.BV >Newin.txt
```

Comment: This one is better than mine.. :)

Comment: Hi, this has worked, but not in the way I was aiming for. The files have been concatenated in a seemingly random order, but I need them in numerical order according to the name of the subdirectory (i.e. 1 > 227).

Comment: @RichieHoward This makes it a different question, but ok. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
root@dib:~# find ./ -type f -name in.BV
./test1/in.BV
./test1/test2/in.BV
```

Find with Exec:

```
root@dib:~# find ./ -type f -name in.BV -exec cat {} + |tee your_new_file.txt
asdf
asdf
```